# How to display a shinyproxy app inside wordpress site

Tags: r, wordpress, shiny, shinyproxy

I have a shiny-proxy app running and a wordpress site on separate servers.

What i want to do is to display the shiny app on my site.

Apparently iframe does not work in wordpress for security reasons.

Any suggestions/solutions to the problem?